# mysql-python fetchrow brings: TypeError: 'long' object is not callable

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I got a table:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Benutzer  | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Confirmed | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

with one entry!

If I execute on the mysql console in a shell:

```
select Benutzer from UserConfirm where Benutzer = '\{\'gid\'\:\ \'tamer\'\,\ \'uid\'\:\ \'tamer\'\}'
```

it works!

At mysql-python there comes the errormessage:

```
TypeError: 'long' object is not callable
```

What did I make wrong?! 
Here is my python code:

```
cursor = self.__db.cursor().execute('select * from UserConfirm where Benutzer = \'' + ds + '\'') 
return cursor().fetchrow()
```

For any advice, I would kindly thank you.

Comment: On a side note, I hope your `ds` variable will never contain the string "'; drop table UserConfirm; --"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not storing the cursor object, just the return value of execute, which is not the cursor, it should be:

```
cursor = self.__db.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from UserConfirm where Benutzer = \'' + ds + '\'') 
return cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: i understand the example is accurate but even simple examples should always parameterize.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I assume your line `cursor().fetchrow()` is a typo and you meant `cursor.fetchrow()`.

Not knowing mysql-python myself, from the error I can assume `cursor.execute` is returning the number of rows or an error code, not the cursor itself.

Try the following instead:

```
cursor = self.__db.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from UserConfirm where Benutzer = \'' + ds + '\'')
return cursor.fetchrow()
```